# Failed to open file '/root/dump.sql', error: 2

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am using PHP version: 7.0.22-0 ubuntu 0.16.04.1. I am trying to upload a .sql access file to MySQL database using the following code

source  /var/lib/mysql/dump.sql

but I get an error

Failed to open file '/root/var/lib/mysql/dump.sql', error: 2

that is the location of the file because when I do a search that's what comes back with.

Comment: what command are you actually typeing. And, what is the '.' doing in command you have shown. Surely you want to have something like mysql < /some/path/dump.sql

Comment: you want to open dump.sql ?

Comment: yes, i use the following source  ~/var/lib/mysql/dump.sql

Comment: sorry,  I think I have given a poor explanation for the problem. I am trying to upload a database to mysql. WIll vim help with that?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was solved by using a ~ before the path name

so instead of using the below 
source /var/lib/mysql/dump.sql

I used the below 
source ~/var/lib/mysql/dump.sql

I don't know enough about the subject to understand by but that fixed that error